# Role based Authorization in ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, roles, authorize

I'm working on creating a role system in ASP.net.
Now it works fine because I can associate roles to users

As you can see here.

[image: AspNetUserRoles]

Now my question is what should I do to get role- based access working.
Because one somehow this does not work.
It sends me as a super admin back to the login page

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Superadmin")]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Web.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="MyConString" connectionString="server=JENSJONKMAN\SQLEXPRESS; database=JensGoesASP; integrated security=true;"/>-->
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=JENSJONKMAN\SQLEXPRESS;     Initial Catalog=JensGoesASP;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="JensGoesASPEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ImageModel.csdl|res://*/ImageModel.ssdl|res://*/ImageModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=JENSJONKMAN\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=JensGoesASP;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Greetz

Comment: Did you set up the aspnet tables on your SQL using aspnet_regsql.exe (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe) or is this something you have built entirely yourself?

Comment: No I have not used aspnet_regsql.exe.
I've added a connection string  to my project and then the tables were automatically created in my database.
But I can just add roles to my database and modify them.

Comment: Show your related configuration in web.config. I believe you need to specify the role provider to get this working.

Comment: Have you setup the roles in `UserPrinciple`?

Comment: I added my Web.config in the post

Comment: @Akshay Umhh i dont think so. Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add roles in `UserPrincipal` in `Global.asax` file

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null) 
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        // Read the roles from cookie
        string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { ',' });

        GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), roles);
        Context.User = userPrincipal;
    }
}
```

Create a customized `Authorize` attribute and override `OnAuthorization` method

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    // Check if the user is authorized to access else redirect to unauthorized page
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```